# Multiple arrays over sorted directories

Tags: bash, associative-array

The following code stores directory names at a particular depth, sorted by size in array `dlc`.

I want to store consecutive elements in `dlc` to the associative array.  Apart from a unique identifier (uid), I could append a further numeric identifier at the beginning.

```
asc[1-uid]=dlc[0]
asc[2-uid]=dlc[1]
asc[3-uid]=dlc[2]

asc[1-uid]=dlc[3]
asc[2-uid]=dlc[4]
asc[3-uid]=dlc[5]

...
```

In this way I can identify the three different arrays in the associative array `asc` using the first numeric value.

This is how I am populating the dlc array.

```
 depth=3
 daggr=( -mindepth "$depth" -maxdepth "$depth" )
 mapfile -td '' dlc <                                     \
   <(find "$src" "${daggr[@]}" -type d -exec du -h0 {} +  \
     | sort -zrh )
 ndr=${#dlc[@]}

 printf '%s\n' "${dlc[@]}"

 echo ""
 for line in "${dlc[@]}"; do
   path=${line#*$'\t'}
   echo "$path"
 done
```

Comment: `I want to make...` Then do it. Do you have a question to ask? What is stopping you? Please see [ask]. `where the first directory name` Note that bash has no 2d arrays, so storing array of arrays is already hard enough. So first implement a method for that. Anyway, so it's: iterate over directories, for each directory run your command and store in that 2d array.

Comment: My question is about how to get the looping structure so that I continue writing the nevt element again to the first array, etc, until the end.

Comment: sooo `for i in "$src" "${daggr[@]}"; do`? What do you mean by "looping structure"?

Comment: use modular arithmetic: `for n in {0..10}; do echo "element $n --> array $(( n%3 +1 ))"; done; echo ...`

Comment: Thanks @jhnc, for showing the modular arithmetic:strategy.

Comment: The `find` command `find "$src" "${daggr[@]}" ...` is currently producing results beyond the specified depth of `3`.